# Preserve original formatting in HTML when parsing with PHP DOM functions

Tags: php, html, dom

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents($inputFile);
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadHTML($html);
    $parsed_html = $document->saveHTML();
?>
```

When I run this against my HTML I want the output to be exactly the same as input. But what I get is:

1. All white space characters in head are removed.
2. All non-ASCII characters are replaced with entities (e.g. `©` to `&Acirc;&copy;`)... That doesn't even seem valid...
3. Some whitespace is removed in body (e.g. whitespace between `<ul>` and `<li>`).

When I use `saveXML` it's a bit better, but my HTML is not valid XML as I'm using HTML5 syntax.

Example HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Copyright:  ©2014 Nux
      License:  CC0
-->

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-lang="en">
            <p>App version 0.1.1.</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Create model with JSON.</li>
                <li>Append views to HTML</li>
                <li>Add interactions in controllers.</li>
                <li>Test in any browser.</li>
                <li>Package.</li>
                <li>Run anywhere.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a [gist with input and output](https://gist.github.com/Eccenux/edfb68f0e4745f16af19).

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am considering doing risky things with `preg_match_all()` and `substr_replace()`, just to keep the formatting the same ;)

Comment: No nice solution yet. I found [this HTML5 parser](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-php), which forces PHP to do more decent parsing, but PHP still replaces entities upon saving.

Comment: same problem with removed spaces, seems like a bug

Comment: `&Acirc;&copy;` looks like UTF-8 parsed as iso-8859-1 and converted to entities. Your HTML might not have been recognized as UTF-8.